# Association of Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`Vote` has_many `Option`,`Options` belongs_to `User` with column `user_id`.

In `vote's` `show.html.erb`

when <% @vote.options.user_id %>     it come an error :`undefined method`user_id'`.

how could i get the `option.user_id` in `Vote's` view?

Answer (score 1):

`@vote.options.first.user_id` should help

to debug you should do `p @vote.options` and get output result in your rails development console among of messages, you will be able to see what's @vote.options consists of.